# Why apollo server custom directive not working?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to implement a custom directive with apollo server. I took the example from the official site.

My query is like below:

```
directive @upper on FIELD_DEFINITION

type Query {
  hello: String @upper
}
```

My resolver is like below:

```
Query:{
        async hello(){
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

Here is my apollo server config for custom directive:

```
const { ApolloServer, SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require("graphql");

class UpperCaseDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
    visitFieldDefinition(field) {
      const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
      field.resolve = async function (...args) {
        const result = await resolve.apply(this, args);
        if (typeof result === "string") {
          return result.toUpperCase();
        }
        return result;
      };
    }
  }

const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    schemaDirectives: {
        upper: UpperCaseDirective
    },
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
    cors: cors()

});
```

The output I always get :

```
{
  "data": {
    "hello": "hello world"
  }
}
```

Why the custom directive is not activated? Why the output is not in uppercase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would pass `schemaDirectives` to `ApolloServer`'s constructor if `ApolloServer` was building your schema for you -- that is, if you were also passing in `resolvers` and `typeDefs`. If you're passing in an existing schema, it's already built and ApolloServer won't apply the directives. If you're using `makeExecutableSchema`, you can pass your `schemaDirectives` to that. It's also possible to manually visit all directives like this:

```
SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitSchemaDirectives(schema, schemaDirectives)
```

This is the only way to get directives to work with certain libraries, like `graphql-modules`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working when I pass in 'makeExecutableSchema'